terminal inserts characters after CTRL+C
in some of my applications (ArchLinux, Gnome 46) some chars are appended to my username when using CTRL+C to abort a script. Sometimes also in the middle of bash scripts, which makes it a bit painful:
(venv) [me@mydesk ansible]$ ^C
[me@mydesk ansible]$ \x1b]633\x3bB(venv) [me@mydesk ansible]$ 

This also happens when not in a venv and in general quite often. The example comes from a terminal within code oss but I have seen it in other applications happening too.

\x1b is the ASCII ESCAPE character (Esc).
The sequence Esc ] is a command sequence introduction (CSI) for an ANSI operating system command (OSC).
Therefore, I would look carefully at what is set up in the PS1 environment variable and maybe look in login scripts (and elsewhere) for interrupt traps involving SIGINT or INT.

References

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code
https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-trap-command

